# Laravel view problems after changing the server

Tags: laravel, iis, laravel-4, windows-server

I'm having a weird problem with Laravel application which has been at Linux Server previously and was working fantastic but while moving to a new IIS Server, I faced alot of problems and the last problem here is some problems in view, while css and JS files are loaded and there is no error in console.
I have posted this question previously, now I'm re-posting it again with more details.
e.g. In local and previous host the fonts are good and everything works correctly, but in IIS server the fonts are bigger than normal and in local and previous server,The Pop Ups are Shown and the fonts are fine [As shown in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNRHm.png), but, in IIS server, The background gets dark but the popup is not shown and the fonts are bigger [Like this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOVTH.png).

When I check it via Inspect elements from Chrome no error is there and all CSS and JS files are loaded correctly, while everything works but all fonts are bigger and some designs are ruined.

What I have tried:

1. I tried `php artisan dump-autoload` and `php artisan serve`.
2. Updated the composer.
3. Cleared the cache.
4. rewrited the mod and removed index.php from the link.

However, none of them works. I'm loading CSS and JS Files this way: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/mystyle.css') }}">` and `<script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>`.
It looks like a very strange and weird problem, I don't know what is wrong while every CSS and JS files as well as every option works fine, but the fonts are bigger, some padding are ignored and some designs are ruined, while in localhost and previous server it was fine.
Can anybody help? and say what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not familiar but any way here some tips :

1. in IIS server you should use URL::secure to connect with assets
2. post some code so we can find something wrong
3. use firefox developer edition to find your css problems in production
4. find the css selectors that effects your font in production

Comment: I did a fresh installation of Laravel using composer at IIS and copied route, controller, view, model and necessary css and js files and the problem is solved. I don't know why sometimes Laravel does this, you do everything but you see nothing and a fresh installation solves the problem. It has been many times, I'm facing such problems, still I don't have a clue on what is wrong. Any idea?